# How do I list the department id and name and then the employees who work in that department underneath the dep name?

Tags: sql

```
select DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME from DEPARTMENTS
union 
select DEPARTMENT_ID, LAST_name from employees
order by 1, 2;
```

but basically ordered in a way that each department has its employees underneath it...

Comment: post sample data and output it will be easier for us to answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add a secondary sort to force the Department line first within your department group.

```
select 'D' as de, DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME from DEPARTMENTS

union 

select 'E' as de, DEPARTMENT_ID, LAST_name from employees 

order by DEPARTMENT_ID, de, LAST_name ;
```